# Pushing regexmatches values out of if else statement

Tags: c#, regex

The end goal of this is to push regex matches into a MySQL database. When multiple files are being read of the program, I will take the regex matches and update to the database. However file details of a file will never change. Below are the file headers that will not change.

However after passing through the program I get index out of range error. I tried substituting the list with strings and initialising the strings as “” before the if else statements but it cause an error in my database as I will append “” statements into the database.

```
        list<string> Time = new list<string>;
        list<string> Name = new list<string>;
        list<string> Gender = new list<string>;

        if (RegexTime.Success)
        {
            Time.add(RegexTime.Value)
        }

        else if (RegexName.Success)
        {
            Name.add(RegexName.value);
        }

        else if (RegexGender.Success)
        {
           Gender.Add(RegexGender.value)
        }

        string Id = Time[0] + "\n" + Name[0] + "\n" + Gender [0];

        Time.Clear();
        Name.Clear();
        Gender.Clear();
```

Comment: Why would their be a 0 index, if there is no success ? also there is no need to use a list here at all

Comment: There would definitely be a success as every file sent will have name, the time and the gender fields. The regex works and is able to get these values. Hence I did an if else statement to only grab values with success inside.

Comment: Did you try checking the count for each list? If any of them are empty, you could encounter this error.

Comment: Ok, you need to learn how to use the step debugger and prove this for your self, we cant help you. one of your lists isn't what you think it is, only you can figure this out .

Comment: Okay thank you all for your help I’ll try and debug the errors!! ((:

Comment: Yeah if, debug first, then if you have an issue you are not sure of, then with all the information we maybe able to help